# C++ Operator overload: stl sort on vector of my custom class

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector, operator-overloading

I have a very basic class that is stored inside an STL Vector. I am trying to sort that vector, but am getting cryptic STL errors. Can someone assist?

```
// Point.h
class Point {
public:
  Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
  Point( float x0, float y0 ) : x(x0), y(y0) {}
  float x;
  float y;
};

// Point.cpp, updated const as per given answers
bool operator< (const Point &p1,const  Point &p2)
{
    return p1.x < p2.x || (p1.x==p2.x && p1.y< p2.y);
}
```

Again, this Point class is stored in a vector and is being sorted:

```
std::vector<Point> tmp=N->points;
std::sort(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
```

Errors:

http://ideone.com/WIv0u

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Try const Point & as the argument to the overload.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding on how to use ideone.com. You put your *program* there, and it will compile and generate the error messages for you. No need to paste the error messages themselves.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You can't have multiple source and header files on ideone, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, you're probably right, but you can insert the contents of the .h at the point where you'd do the `#include`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: He would, presumably, also have to insert the contents of his Point implementation file, in which case, he would not have had the same errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bool operator< (`**`const`**`Point &p1,`**`const`**`Point &p2 )`

Comment: Just tried this, I also had to move the operator implementation to a .cpp file because g++ was complaining about duplicate definitions- still no dice. Getting crazy amounts of errors, I will update the original post in a second with a pastebin of the errors.

Comment: @Joseph: After you moved the implemetation to the cpp file, do you have a declaration(the signature without the body) in the header? visible in the place where you use `std::sort`?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify that? In the code where I am using std::sort, I have included "Point.h" and I am compiling g++ main.cpp otherstuff.cpp Point.cpp. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Better than moving it to another file may be to add `inline` to the function: `inline bool operator<( const Point &p1, const Point &p2)`.

Comment: @Joseph: You said you moved the operator implementation to a .cpp file.  That's well and good. But you still want to have this line in the header file: `bool operator<(const Point &,const  Point &);` -- Do you?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Duh, no I did not. Adding that in there seems to have fixed it all!

Comment: @Joseph: Another option would be what Michael Anderson said.  Keep the definition in the header file, but add `inline` in front of it.